# segmentation fault looping through 2-D pointer array

Tags: c, loops, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I loop through this 2-d pointer array

declaration:

```
char **addr;

addr=malloc((y)*sizeof(char)); //y is 3
for(i=0;i<y;i++)
{
        *(addr+i)=malloc(x*sizeof(char)); //x is 100
}
```

independent access works:

```
*(*(addr+2)+0)='a';
printf("%c\n",*(*(addr+2)+0));
```

loop returns a segmentation fault at addr[2][0] regardless of what y and x are

```
for(j=0;j<x;j++)
{
        for(i=0;i<y;i++)
        {
                printf("%d %d\n",j,i);
                *(*(addr+j)+i)='a';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
addr=malloc((y)*sizeof(char));
```

must be replaced by

```
addr = malloc(y * sizeof(char *));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `X *x = malloc(sizeof *x)` idiom when allocating memory :

```
addr = malloc(y * sizeof *addr);
```

So the result of `sizeof` actually refers to the type of the data you're pointing to :

```
sizeof *addr == sizeof(char *)
```

Comment: +1 Of the two methods generally used to do this,, I prefer this one only because it is universal to any level of indirection your pointer is taking on. The line is identical for single, triple, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are good.  This is just an alternative you may consider.  It is a way to do what you are doing, that also will help to free the memory properly (which is sometimes a pain with multi-pointer arrays)

Define functions to do the work:

```
char ** allocMemory(char ** a, int numStrings, int maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    a = calloc(sizeof(char*)*(numStrings+1), sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(sizeof(char)*maxStrLen+ 1, sizeof(char));
    }
    return a;
}

void freeMemory(char ** a, int numStrings)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
        if(a[i]) free(a[i]);
    free(a);  
}
```

Then you can simply call these functions with parameters you have created for any number of strings, with a max string length, then free the same with a pre-configured function.

So your code would look like this:

```
char **addr;  

addr = allocMemory(addr, 100, 3);  //100 strings of max length == 3
```

Then, when you are done with addr:

```
freeMemory(addr, 100); //free 100 strings, and associated pointers.
```